# remove data greater than 95th percentile in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data like this:

df:

```
Group   Point
A       6000
B       5000
C       1000
D        100
F        70
```

Before I graph this df, I only like to remove values over than 95th percentile in my data frame. Any body tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the `quantile` function

```
> quantile(d$Point, 0.95)
 95% 
5800 

> d[d$Point < quantile(d$Point, 0.95), ]
  Group Point
2     B  5000
3     C  1000
4     D   100
5     F    70
```

Answer (score 13):

Or using 'dplyr' library:

```
> quantile(d$Point, 0.95)
 95% 
5800

> df %>% filter(Point < quantile(df$Point, 0.95))
  Group Point
1     B  5000
2     C  1000
3     D   100
4     F    70
```

Comment: You can even go a little shorter without specifying `df`: `df %>% filter(Point < quantile(Point, 0.95))`.