# Replace and delete first and last percentile in dataframe or multiple columns at once

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
A <- paste0("event_", c(1:100))
some_number <- sample.int(1000,size=100) 
X1 <- c(1:100)
X2 <- c(101:200)
X3 <- c(201:300)
X4 <- c(301:400)
X5 <- c(401:500)
DF <- data.frame(A, some_number, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5)
```

As I'm treating outliers, I'm looking to delete the rows that contains the 1th and the latest percentile, considering only the `X` variables for the percentile computation and all `X` variables as ONE group. Hence, the percentiles will consider `X1` to `X5` as ONE group. For this it occurs to me these steps:

1. Replace the values of `X1` to `X5` with 1 to 100 (1 for each percentile). Remember, I'm not looking for the percentiles of each `X`, but for all X's as a whole.
2. Delete the rows where the variables `X1` to `X5` contains 1 or 100

My attempt: (based on [how to find percentiles](https://www.programmingr.com/tutorial/how-to-find-percentiles-in-r/#:%7E:text=You%20find%20a%20percentile%20in,value%20that%20is%20the%20percentile.&text=This%20is%20the%20default%20version,75th%20percentile%2C%20and%20100th%20percentile.), [replace outliers with the 5th and 95th percentile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339685/how-to-replace-outliers-with-the-5th-and-95th-percentile-values-in-r), [remove data greater than 95th percentile in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519629/remove-data-greater-than-95th-percentile-in-data-frame))

```
as.data.frame(sapply(select(DF, X1:X5), function (x) {
     qx <- quantile(x, probs = c(1:100)/100)
     cut(x, qx, labels = c(1:100))
}))
```

But.. my attempt raises the error that the number of breaks is different to the number of labels, I'm struggling to assign the new dataframe without losing `A` and `some_number` variables (in my real problem they are not two columns, but nearly 50)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `sapply` you are calculating quantile for each column separately. If you want to consider all the X variables as whole do you want to remove rows where value is outside this range `quantile(as.matrix(DF[3:7]), c(0.01, 0.99))` ?

Comment: You have 99 levels `nlevels(cut(DF$X1, quantile(DF$X1, probs = c(1:100)/100)))` and are assigning 100 labels.

Comment: @RonakShah yes, that's right. thelatemail do you know how can I create that additional level in order to match the 100 labels? (Because it's 100 percentiles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using both `across` and `c_across` in `dplyr`, you may also do this-

Steps explained -

- `c_across` is usually used with `row_wise` as it creates a complete copy of data subsetted through its inner argument.  But I have done it without `rowwise()` so instead of creating one row it is creating a copy of whole data as desired.
- thereafter two quantiles of this data will be deduced. (which will be scalar quantities)
- Now only job remains is to to check these values with every other value in data.  So I used here `across` directly.
- Using across I built a lambda formula which starts with a `twiddle` and its argument is `.` only.  This twiddle style formula `~ .` is equivalent to `function(x) x` and the rest is clear.

```r
DF %>% mutate(across(starts_with('X'), ~ifelse(. > quantile(c_across(starts_with('X')), 0.99) |
                                                 . < quantile(c_across(starts_with('X')), 0.01),
                                               NA, .) 
                     )) %>% na.omit()

#>           A some_number X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
#> 6   event_6          69  6 106 206 306 406
#> 7   event_7         871  7 107 207 307 407
#> 8   event_8         356  8 108 208 308 408
.
.
.
#> 93 event_93         432 93 193 293 393 493
#> 94 event_94         967 94 194 294 394 494
#> 95 event_95         516 95 195 295 395 495
```

---

Since `starts_with` works only in `across` or `c_across` and to avoid slower `rowwise` here, we can also do this directly

```
DF %>% filter(rowSums(cur_data()[str_detect(names(DF), 'X')] > quantile(c_across(starts_with('X')), 0.99)) == 0 &
                rowSums(cur_data()[str_detect(names(DF), 'X')] < quantile(c_across(starts_with('X')), 0.01)) == 0)
```

This will also give 90 rows in output as desired

Comment: Could you explain a little bit what does the first bunch of code? Specifically how mutate actually creates the column without using '=', and the use of ~. as my intuition tell me it's not used as negation. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris, my pleasure.  See the edit please.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following -

```
library(dplyr)
vec <- DF %>% select(starts_with('X')) %>% as.matrix() %>% quantile(c(0.01, 0.99))

DF %>% filter(if_all(starts_with('X'), ~. > vec[1] & . < vec[2]))
```